# Как взять значение из исходного кода сайта?

Tags: php

Как взять определённое значение из исходного кода определённого сайта?

Например, из исходного кода сайта *vk.com/foaf.php?id=1*
Я хочу взять значение `<ya:created dc:date="(значение)"/>`

PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Предложу альтернативный вариант:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://vk.com/foaf.php?id=1');
$dt = new DateTime((string) $xml->xpath('//ya:created/@dc:date')[0]);

echo $dt->format('Y.m.d');
```

Comment: Ваше решение лучше :<

Comment: @Manitikyl, стоит пару раз услышать критику от профи о том, что парсинг xml, html регулярками — зло, сразу стоит искать альтернативы, хд) Иногда они выглядят изящнее :) UPD (набью тату REGEXP)

Answer (score 3):

Ну в самом простом варианте, можно через регулярку:

```
$url = 'https://vk.com/foaf.php?id=1';
$file = file_get_contents($url);
preg_match_all('#<ya:created dc:date="(.*)"/>#U', $file, $out, PREG_SET_ORDER);
if (isset($out[0])) {
    $date = $out[0][1];
    $dt = new DateTime($date);
    var_dump($dt->format('Y.m.d'));
}
```

А вообще есть всякие RDF либы, лучше с ними работать, они вам тот результат как массив на изичах представят.

Comment: Результат приходит в таком формате: array(2) { [0]=> string(49) "" [1]=> string(25) "2006-09-23T20:27:12+03:00" }

Можно преобразовать его в формат 2006.09.23?
Если да, то как?

Comment: @Амин можно, если хорошо попросите :)

Comment: @Амин Добавил в ответ.

Comment: плюсик, за регулярочку :)